# Is there a way to sort nuget.org results by last updated date?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Is there a way to sort nuget.org results by last updated date so that recently updated packages show up first? I see no option to sort by anything. 
In Visual Studio is fine too.

Comment: Hi Tony, could you please share more details about how you sort the nuget.org results? By command-line or nuget.org web UI?

Comment: I am looking for any method to sort as long as it works. Preferably on the site. Just like Github.com. There's a sort dropdown. This has been requested for years! Why can't we have one just like the Github one. Sort by most/least recent updated date. Least/most downloaded count. I might be interested in using a package that is currently active so I want to see the Recently Updated ones at the top of the results.

Answer (score -1):

> In Visual Studio is fine too.

Sorry but VS for now doesn't support sort nuget by `last updated date`.

The nuget package manager in VS function once came from Nuget Package Manager extension, and so far it has been integrated into VS component. In current version, no option in VS can change or manage this behavior.

For your requirements, I post one feature request in VS's user voice forum. You can track it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/894920/an-opinion-support-sorting-results-by-last-update.html) and if it gets enough votes, the team would consider it seriously. Hope it makes some help for you :)

Update from **zivkan's** hint(set source as nuget.org):

[image]

[image]

Similar to what **zivkan** describes below, the result order in VS PMUI is up to each nuget source's search service to determine the best order. And it's obvious that we can't specify the order with `last updated date`.

Comment: In VS's Package Manager UI, when "all sources" is searched, it uses some heuristic to merge results, but I don't believe it actually sorts by download count. When the source dropdown selected a single source, PMUI shows results in the same order as the search service responded with. So it's up to each nuget source's search service to determine the best order.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll check it and improve the answer later :)